# ADO.NET Entity Framework - Pre-Generate Views -

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

We are using ADO.NET Entity for our ASP.NET application.

I have read that the pre-generated views improves the performance. Referred to the blog post,

http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx, I generated the views. The namespace & classes generated as

```
namespace Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews
{


    /// <Summary>
    /// The type contains views for EntitySets and AssociationSets that were generated at design time.
    /// </Summary>
    public sealed class ViewsForBaseEntitySets4D4A6E0AA7AF6B2298FABB4F22235831 : System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewContainer
    {

        /// <Summary>
        /// The constructor stores the views for the extents and also the hash values generated based on the metadata and mapping closure and views
        /// </Summary>
        public ViewsForBaseEntitySets4D4A6E0AA7AF6B2298FABB4F22235831()
        {
            this.EdmEntityContainerName = "JSEntities";
```

I added this to my data layer and test the performance. Couldn't see much improvement. CPU usage always goes to 20-30% utilization (response timing is good) and reduce back to 0% in 500ms - 1 sec. I think the CPU utilization goes high because of view generation every time.

I couldn't understand how the entity framework knows that this is my pre-generated view class for my model eventhough the MyModel.edmx & MyModel.Views.cs matches with filename.

Should I have to update Web.Config or App.Config to map the View class to model somewhere?

Please clarify.

Comment: Check which process is using the CPU. Is your SQL Server on the same machine?

Answer (score 5):

I've been wondering the same thing and been doing some digging.

As far as I can tell the generated class file contains an assembly level attribute, `EntityViewGenerationAttribute`, which defines the class type that contains the pre-compiled view.
Then, and here im only making educated guesses, at compile time the class must be loaded via reflection and in some way bound to the queries the view defines. Possibly in the ESQL cache, which would makea certain amount of sense.

Even though the view's are pre-compiled they only produce ESQL, not the actual TSQL which will be ran. However pre-compiling views does allow the execution of a query to skip the validation and ESQL generation step which should offer a slight performance gain, especially for large compilcated queries.